# Android random number not clearing from memory

Tags: android, random, spinner

I have a dice roll spinner in my app that should drop down and display two options, based on the option clicked it should display a random number in that range. My issue now is that, and it could be because of the onItemSelced listener, but when you select an option from the spinner and get your random number you can not chose the same option without first chosing the other option. Example is if two people want to roll the D6, after the first random number is displayed, you MUST click D20 and get a random number, before you can again select the D6. I do not know how to fix this issue.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected.
     if (firstrun)
        {
            firstrun = false;
            return;
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
    int roll = rand.nextInt(DICE[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()])+1;

    // Put the result into a string.
    String text = "You rolled a " + roll;

    // Build a dialog box and with the result string and a single button
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // do things when the user clicks ok.
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    // Show the dialog box.
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: "would it be better" better in what way? And what do you mean you've been unsuccessful? Maybe try something, which you think should work, and see.

Comment: Better in terms of code execution, I am rather new at java/android. I did try a if statement but it did not seem to matter what was selected from the spinner as it always only rolled a D20

Comment: Hmm then you probably made an error somewhere in the implementation. What I tend to do, when it comes to random numbers, is to get a number from 0 to 1 and then scale it appropriately (in this case by multiplying times 6 or 20, as required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this lines are the problem

> // An item was selected.
>
> int roll = DICE[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
>
> ```
>    roll = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
> ```

The first line is not used, because you assign another value to "roll" in the next line
If you save in DICE the values 6 and 20, this would be a solution

```
int roll = rand.nextInt(DICE[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()])+1;
```

otherwise this should work

```
if (spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
{
    roll = rand.nextInt(6)+1;  // this line was corrected after a comment
}
else
{
    roll = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
}
```

i hope this helped
Thomas

-- the next day

Hi, i wrote it down and tested it. This is working with my Eclipse-environment

res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">StackOverflow</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>


    <string-array name="dice">
        <item>6</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>20</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Java-class

```
package tbn.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Starter extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    // check twice that this array and the array in res/values/string have the same order!!
    int DICE[] = {6,10,20};
    Spinner spinner1;
    boolean firstrun = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        fillSpinner();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starter, menu);
        return true;
    }
    
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        if (firstrun)
        {
            firstrun = false;
            return;
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        int roll = rand.nextInt(DICE[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()]) + 1;

        // Put the result into a string.
        String text = "You rolled a " + roll;

        // a Textview is faster for testing
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(text);
        
//      // Build a dialog box and with the result string and a single button
//      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//      builder.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//              // do things when the user clicks ok.
//          }
//      });
//      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
//
//      // Show the dialog box.
//      alert.show();
    }
    
    private void fillSpinner()
    {
        // Copied from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.dice, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The call to random in the else statement should be bounded at 6 (not at 20), but this is the right idea.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. When I tried the if/else myself I did not set the ==0. I also wanted to mention that when the app starts, before anything is even selected, it pops up a random number like it has been pressed. What do I need to set to false to keep that from happening?

Comment: I just tried your method Thomas, the issue now is that the value of roll is not released at all so after getting one random number it stays in the value of roll such that all other times I try to get a random number it only returns the first value given. example is if my first roll is D20 and it returns a 3, all other rolls on both D6 and D20 will only return a 3

Comment: Hi @user2980560 i expanded my code in the posting above. This should be a working version for your demands.
greetings

Comment: I get an error at the textbox1. I have no textbox1 in my xml sheet, what is it referencing?

Comment: two solutions: 
1. just add a Textview to your app and use the id textView1
2. just delete the two lines below the line "// a Textview is faster for testing"
and uncomment your Dialogbox

Comment: 20 only returns 1. 6 will return any variable in the range of 20. Instead of using a spinner would it be better to have a button that when clicked will bring up a clickable list of the dice?

Comment: I updated my code, it is working now but I can not chose the same option twice in a row without choosing the other first.

Comment: That is the nature of a spinner. It only react, if the selection changes. Again two solutions.

1. Change your whole App and use buttons for each dice instead of one spinner for all dice.
2. Add one Button. If this one is pushed use the last selected dice.

If you will extend your App to a D4, D10 and so on i would advice to use the second option.